# Port-Forwarding (Issue with ISP?)

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

I have a ZyXel router, model: VMG1312-B30B

I have setup port forwarding rules on the router configuration, turned-off the firewall and restarted the router. I've been running netcat on my linux machine and using canyouseeme.org and other sites to test if the port is opened with no success. (Also when I do an nmap scan on the ports [from within the LAN] it says the ports are filtered, not open)

After reading this article http://blog.kleissner.org/?p=369

I think it may be an issue with my ISP. Is this possible?

The default gateway is 10.0.0.138
When I look in my router configuration, under Device info WAN I see that it has another local address, shouldn't this be a public address? The port forwarding does work using this address but only from inside the LAN.

Interface | Ipv4 Address

ppp1.1 | 10.227.139.157

is it normal to have 2 local addresses like that?

There's 2 other configurations that I haven't looked at, do I have to change something here?

One is Advanced Setup --- WAN Service

The other is Advanced Setup --- Routing --- Default Gateway

pics here:

[router config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBz1e.png)

[another config image](https://s9.postimg.org/94t1scpwb/image.png)

Comment: Also when I scan the ipv6 address, nmap reports the ports as closed....

Comment: I updated the question to add the extra link :) You could delete your other comment

Comment: Your images are way to small to be readable.

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](http://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. Suppose I should try with a vpn?